# Mysql запросы к базе данных в цикле

Tags: php, mysql

Нужно чтобы в базу данных в определенную таблицу внеслись записиь с 5 по 1455.
Я делаю так:

```
<?
$dbhost = "localhost"; // Хост
$dbuser = "user"; // Имя пользователя
$dbpassword = "pass"; // Пароль
$dbname = "dbname"; // Имя базы данных

$link = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword);

mysql_select_db($dbname, $link);

$x = 5;
while (x < 1455):
$query = "insert into b_user_group values(".$x.",'8','NULL', 'NULL')";
$x++;
endwhile;
mysql_query($query, $link);

mysql_close($link);?>
```

Но не работает почему-то. В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Какие поля в базе?

Comment: Кстати, кто знает, какой лимит запросов к mysql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы запрос формируете в цикле, а выполняете его вне цикла. Один раз.

Comment: Он сделал до 21 ячейки и начал их плюсовать.
Получается такого вида: 1967019 8 0000-00-00 00:00:00 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Answer (score 4):

```
$x = 5;
$query = "insert into b_user_group values ";
$comma = 0;
while (x < 1455) {
  if ($comma) { $query .= ', '; } else $comma++;
  $query .= '('.$x.',\'8\',NULL, NULL)';
  $x++;
  }
$query .= ';';
mysql_query($query, $link);
```

Comment: Так как в данном случае два последних поля постоянно NULL, я бы добавил в основную часть запроса поля, которые необходимо инициализировать, а остальные исключил бы из запроса.

    INSERT INTO table (field1, field2) VALUES ... 

А дальше, как у @Sh4dow окромя

    $query .= '('.$x.',\'8\')';

Answer (score 1):

цикл while должен выглядеть так:

```
while ($x < 1455):
$query = "insert into b_user_group values('".$x++."','8','NULL', 'NULL')";
mysql_query($query, $link);
endwhile;
```

Comment: Он все еще плюсует.

Comment: Интересно, сколько времени он будет плюсовать? Видел я одного такого уникума, который папки и файлы на муз. сервере перебирал каждый час по пять минут. Вот точно таким же образом.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost"; // Хост
$dbuser = "user"; // Имя пользователя
$dbpassword = "pass"; // Пароль
$dbname = "dbname"; // Имя базы данных
$link = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword);
mysql_select_db($dbname, $link);

$x = 5;
$values = '';
while ( x < 1455 ) {
  if ( empty($values) ) {
    $values .= '(' . $x . ',8,"NULL","NULL")';
  } else {
    $values .= ',(' . $x . ',8,"NULL","NULL")';
  }
  $x++;
}
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `b_user_group` VALUES ' . $values;
mysql_query($sql, $link);
mysql_close($link);
```